# Powering a phone with SATA to USB Y cable

Tags: hard-drive, usb, sata

Can a Usb to Sata adapter similar to this [USB 3.0 to SATA](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32984039074.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.562d4e169PQs8T&s=p&ad_pvid=202004291056411766838294695000001002893_4&algo_pvid=771bcd1f-75b9-4d71-baff-e58c118ad3e2&algo_expid=771bcd1f-75b9-4d71-baff-e58c118ad3e2-3&btsid=0be3769015881830016746075eacc2&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) be used to power a smartphone from the second Usb cable when a HDD is connected to the phone?

Comment: Why not just use a readily available AC Adapter plug (wall wart) or a second USB port on your computer. Most every computer has at least two USB ports if not 3

Comment: @John The point is the OP wants to charge their phone and access the hard drive from it at the same time, with no computer in the picture.

Comment: I understand but 95 days of 100 I charge overnight and that is good for the next day until evening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a USB hub to simultaneously charge a tablet and connect a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/1136336/can-i-use-a-usb-hub-to-simultaneously-charge-a-tablet-and-connect-a-usb-drive)

Comment: What you need is called "accessory charger adapter". It has nothing to do with USB protocol, master-slave or else. see https://superuser.com/a/1136353/620011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The hard drive needs to **receive** power from **both** of the USB cables.

Comment: Yes, i guess if it receives power from both USB cables cant use to charge the phone at the same time. Probably i will need to use something like this : [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000152358851.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.47652aa92V3yrM&algo_pvid=634c4027-7ec1-4ce3-9b52-f390ca1a6951&algo_expid=634c4027-7ec1-4ce3-9b52-f390ca1a6951-49&btsid=0ab6f83115881862984565692e086a&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

Comment: That will work if you have the smaller USB port on your computer. Also very much watch and be aware of total power requirements of all your devices on the one port.

Comment: Actually i want to connect the hdd to a phone, no computer.

Comment: @user5425461 Not easily. USB is a master-slave protocol. Master connector is what you can see in your laptop. There is only a single master on an USB bus. You can not connect directly a master and a slave. Also the phones have slave connectors.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica USB-OTG lets a phone be a master.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Wow!!! !!!

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica What if the phone is bound to the USB-OTG cable, which is bound to an USB hub with external power, and that is bound to the HDD?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica USB hubs generally don't provide power to their upstream port, only to their downstream ones.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I am thinking on this chain: `phone->usb_otg->usb_hub->usb_sata_adapter->sata_hdd`. So the usb hub would be *between* the otg and the hdd.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica That would work for the phone to use the HDD, but the phone wouldn't receive power. I think the OP wants the phone to be able to receive power.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes. It seems, yet another usb hub is needed, between the phone and the `usb_otg`.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I don't think that would work either, barring something like USB-PD.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Imagine this chain: `phone<-usb_hub_1<-usb_otg->usb_hub_2->usb_sata_adapter->sata_hdd`. Here the arrow shows also the master->slave direction. `usb_hub_1`'s uplink would be the otg device, and the phone would be on his down(s).

Comment: USB hubs don't support OTG in that direction.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Ok. USB has 4 pins, 2 for data and 2 for power. I could solder easily a cable which draws power from another source, but connects the data pins to the OTG. Probably there is such cable cheaply on the market, too.

Answer (score 0):

The second cable is a power only cable meant for when a single port dosen't give enough power.

If you somehow managed to plug in a type A male cable to charge a phone (I guess you could with an OTG adaptor)... you still may not be charging it, and the drive might not have enough power to run correctly.

So... just don't be too clever .

Answer (score -1):

Not easily. USB is a master-slave protocol.

Master connector is what you can see in your laptop. There is only a single master on an USB bus. You can connect directly a master and many slaves. There is no way to connect masters to masters, or slaves to slaves.

Also the phones have slave connectors.

There are devices which can bridge the gap, for example they can act as a master for both the slaves. They require software support, thus they can require rooted android and rebuilt kernel (and completely impossible with any i* thing).